# Disabling Services under the Service tab in msconfig

Tags: windows-xp, windows-service

My computer is getting a bit slow nowadays, especially during startup when I press the "start" button on my computer and wait for it to load my desktop completely.

Is there any side effects if I disable some of the service in the service tab, in msconfig?

I mean, if I disable any of those services, will my computer still able to boot?

Answer (score 2):

There's a little checkbox at the bottom of the window that says "Hide all Microsoft Services".  Before randomly disabling services, check this box so that you only disable new things that have been added over time.

Two other great resources for troubleshooting slow boot times are:

Autoruns (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) which will show you everything that runs at startup (there are many different places beyond what MSConfig shows)

and

Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) which will allow you to enable boot-time logging.  You can turn on the logging, reboot the computer, stop the log, and then analyze the log after rebooting to see what exactly is taking up the boot time (you may find it is just an out of date driver somewhere that just needs to be updated).

Answer (score 1):

[Black Viper](http://www.blackviper.com/WinXP/servicecfg.htm) is a well known resource for understanding a lot of standard services and what effect they will have if you turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

The black viper guide is very good but I'm generally of the opinion that you shouldn't fiddle with things you don't understand.

You're likely to get far more profit from tidying up the system and un-installing stuff you don't use than you are from changing services around.

Comment: I agree. Disabling system services is pretty much a dark art. It's very easy to render your system unbootable, and hard to fix if you do.